# Integration of a composite function containing hermite polynomials.

Tags: calculus, integration, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, hermite-polynomials

I was trying to solve the quantum harmonic oscillator problem. It is almost done, just the normalization of the wave function is left.

$Ψ_n = β_n\mathcal{H}_n(\frac{x}{\alpha})e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\alpha^2}}$;

$\mathcal{H}_n$ is the physicist's hermite polynomial, $\alpha$ is a constant.

For normalizing, I need to find the constant $β_n$.

Using the law of total probability;

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\psi^*\psi dx = 1$

$\Rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} [β_n\mathcal{H}_n(\frac{x}{\alpha})e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\alpha^2}}]^2 dx= 1$

$\Rightarrow \beta_n^2 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \alpha[\mathcal{H}_n(\frac{x}{\alpha})e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\alpha^2}}]^2  \frac{dx}{\alpha} = 1$

$\Rightarrow \beta_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \alpha[\mathcal{H}_n(\frac{x}{\alpha})e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\alpha^2}}]^2  \frac{dx}{\alpha}}}$

I don't know how to start with the solving of the integral in the equation.

But, I am really interested to know how the integral is solved and the value of $\beta_n$ is derived.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287851/how-to-prove-this-integral-involving-derivatives-of-e-x2?noredirect=1

Comment: More generally, look at their orthogonality properties.

Answer (score 0):

From the [orthogonality relation of said polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Orthogonality),
$$  \beta_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{{\alpha}\sqrt{\pi} 2^n n! }}~~.$$